# #TAble is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server-2008, temp-tables, self-join

I am getting an error that states #Plans is ambiguous.  This happens when I am joining a table to itself on a self join and am not sure why.  Here is the code that leads to the error:

```
Alter Table #Plans
Add SecondPlanDate date

Update #Plans
Set 
    SecondPlanDate = Min (P2.PlanPurchaseDate) Over (Partition By P1.PatientID, P1.PlanPurchaseDate)
From
#Plans as P1
Inner Join
#Plans as P2
on
P1.PatientID = P2.PatientID
Where
P2.PlanPurchaseDate > P1.PlanPurchaseDate
;

Select
*
From
#Plans
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use the table alias:

```
UPDATE P1
SET P1.SecondPlanDate ...
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f12c68)

Answer (score 1):

Modify query to

```
Update P1
Set 
    P1.SecondPlanDate = Min (P2.PlanPurchaseDate) Over (Partition By P1.PatientID, P1.PlanPurchaseDate)
From
#Plans as P1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE #Plans
SET SecondPlanDate = P2.FirstPlanPurchaseDate
FROM #Plans P1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT PatientID,
                    MIN(PlanPurchaseDate) AS FirstPlanPurchaseDate
             FROM #Plans
             GROUP BY PatientID) P2
ON P1.PatientID = P2.PatientID
```

Comment: Actually- Doesn't quite work.  Sorry- only pulls the earliest date, not looking for the earliest date.  Looking for earliest date in P2 that is greater than P1's date.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update #Plans
Set 
SecondPlanDate = <your value>
From
#Plans , #Plans  P2
Where
#Plans.PatientID = P2.PatientID
and P2.PlanPurchaseDate > #Plans.PlanPurchaseDate
//ie the solution is to reference the update table in the join as well
```